# How can I install Autobahn only (for use only with asyncio rather than Twisted), without the entire Crossbar package bloat, in Python 3 on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, autobahn

I'm trying to install Autobahn on Python 3.6.0 on Windows, for use only with asyncio rather than Twisted (i.e. I don't need Twisted at all).

I know it should be possible to install only Autobahn, lean-and-mean, **without** needing the entire Crossbar package bloat (where the latter requires Python build tools and whatnot, and the never-ending cascade of problems that comes with that on Windows), but I just cannot seem to find one single relevant Google hit about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the following command on your Windows system:

> pip install autobahn

And yes, I created (and self-answered) this entire question just in order to help others avoid the same apparent extreme lack of (efficiently Google-indexed at least) explicit internet documentation on how to achieve this, that I had to suffer through myself. Enjoy!